# Query to get any 2 EmpCode for every EmpGroup

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to write an SQL Query

To get any 2 `EmpCode` for every `EmpGroup` for `city = del`

- `EmpCode` is unique
- 1 `EmpCode` can have only 1 `EmpGroup`
- 1 `EmpGroup` can have multiple `EmpCodes`

**Table**: EMP_CITY

```
EmpCode  EmpGroup   City
1         A          del
2         A          del
3         B          del
4         B          del
5         C          del
6         C          del
7         A          ban
8         A          del
```

**Output**

```
EmpGroup: A
    1
    2
EmpGroup: B
    3
    4
EmpGroup: C
    5
    6
```

Comment: what about 7,8 it should come under empgroup A or not

Comment: @SRIRAM He should only two empcodes for each group any twos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
SET @level = 0;
SET @group = '';

SELECT 
EmpCode,EGroup
FROM (
    SELECT 
        City,
        EmpCode,
        EmpGroup,
        @level := IF(@group = EmpGroup, @level+1, 1) AS level, 
        @group := EmpGroup as EGroup 
    FROM test
    ORDER BY EmpGroup 
) rs
WHERE level < 3
```

Out put

```
EMPCODE     EGROUP
1           A
2           A
3           B
4           B
5           C
6           C
```

Here is sqlfiddle [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bfa8b/16)

Answer (score 0):

1. You will have to get the entire result set, and then print 2 results from each emp group.

   ```
   select EmpCode, EmpGroup, City
     from EMP_CITY
    ORDER BY EmpGroup
   ```
2. You can get the EmpGroup in your app; then run distinct queries for each Emp group. This would be faster than #1 only when each emp group has numerous employees; such that the extra overhead of individual queries is negated by the fewer number of overall returned rows.

   ```
   select DISTINCT EmpGroup
     from EMP_CITY
    ORDER BY EmpGroup

   select EmpCode, City
     from EMP_CITY
    where EmpGroup = ? limit 2
   ```

   `?` being the various emp groups

Answer (score 0):

use top if available

```
SELECT TOP 2 EMPCODE FROM EMPLIST WHERE EMPGROUP=A
```

If its not availeble then try this

```
SELECT EMPCODE FROM EMPLIST WHERE EMPGROUP=A LIMIT 2
```

For oracle try this

```
SELECT EMPCODE FROM EMPLIST WHERE EMPGROUP=A and ROWNUM<3
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:

```
SELECT EmpGroup, EmpCode
FROM EMP_CITY a
WHERE EmpCode <= (
  SELECT EmpCode
  FROM Emp_CITY b
  WHERE EmpGroup = a.EmpGroup
  LIMIT 1, 1
)
```

I try to get row number 2 EmpCode group by EmpGroup **WHERE EmpGroup = a.EmpGroup** then I select where EmpCode is less than or equals with row number that I get in sub query.

Comment: This wouldn't work when there is only one record for a group. In that case the group is not displayed in the result.

Comment: In case of only 1 record, that particular record should be shown