# SQL: Limit and Randomize results in join

Tags: mysql, select, join, random, limit

I am building a shopping system that finds items at nearby locations.  Basically, each Location (a vendor) has an entry in a table called Location, with has columns for name, latitude, longitude and others... Then there is a table of items, with a foreign key that identifies which location the item belongs to.

Basically, I want to find all the items that are near a user: which I can do with the query below:

However I would like to do the following
- Choose the items from the location randomly
- Limit the number of items from each location to only a few (say 5)
- Randomize all results so they not presented grouped by location

This is by far the must difficult query I have done, im getting better but am so stuck on this one -  any help if very appreciated! THANK YOU!!

Here is my select statement so far:

```
SELECT Location.idLocation
 , Location.locationName
 , Location.tagline
 , Location.tags
 , Location.shortAddress
 , (3959 * acos(cos(radians('40.181')) * cos(radians(Location.latitude)) * cos(radians(Location.longitude) - radians('-74.0265')) + sin(radians('40.181')) * sin(radians(Location.latitude)))) AS distance
 , Item.idItem
 , Item.dateAdded
 , Item.fidLocation
 , Item.itemName
 , Item.description
 , Item.fullImageName
 , Item.thumbnailImageName
FROM
  Location
INNER JOIN Item
ON Location.idLocation = Item.fidLocation
HAVING distance < '1000'
```

Comment: `order by rand() limit 5` is the quick/dirty/cheap/expensive method.

Comment: do you want to select 5 items from each location randomly and then how do you want to order them?

Comment: Thanks. Yes max 5 items from each location, not 5 items total.

Comment: can you provide structure of tables and sample data with desired output

Comment: raheel, will put that together & post it. Don't think I fully answered ur question tho. The idea behind this is to help people discover things are around them, while the data is very well structured, results should be a very varied distribution of items from within the search radius from different vendors.

I tried Marc B's suggestion to just order the results by rand and for now that seems to be working ok.

We don't have a huge data set entered yet for testing so I think I will stick with rand for right now and in a week or two when we have good sample data I will see how it performs.

Comment: It will probably be easier to select N items per location in the application code rather than SQL. This is difficult to do in MySQL because it doesn't have a RANK or ROWNUM operator.

Comment: Well selecting 5 records from each group is what you can do [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119070/query-to-get-any-2-empcode-for-every-empgroup) is example

Answer (score 0):

OK.Here is untested version based on assumption.

```
SELECT
  Location.idLocation,
  Location.locationName,
  Location.tagline,
  Location.tags,
  Location.shortAddress,
  (3959 * acos(cos(radians('40.181')) * cos(radians(Location.latitude)) * cos(radians(Location.longitude) - radians('-74.0265')) + sin(radians('40.181')) * sin(radians(Location.latitude)))) AS distance,
  Item.idItem,
  Item.dateAdded,
  Item.fidLocation,
  Item.itemName,
  Item.description,
  Item.fullImageName,
  Item.thumbnailImageName
FROM Location
  INNER JOIN (select *
          from Item
          order by RAND()
          limit 5) as Item
    ON Location.idLocation = Item.fidLocation
ORDER BY RAND()
HAVING distance < '1000'
```

Comment: That will just select 5 total items, not 5 per location. And then it will filter out any that are more than 1,000 miles (or km, I'm not sure) away, so you'll probably get nothing.

Comment: removing limit five what is the result?

Comment: Then you'll get everything, just like the query in the question.

Comment: Thanks Raheel, tried that, but yes Barmar is correct. That selects 5 total items.

Answer (score 0):

```
SET @local = 0;
SET @group = 0;

SELECT Location.idLocation
 , Location.locationName
 , Location.tagline
 , Location.tags
 , Location.shortAddress
 , (3959 * acos(cos(radians('40.181')) * cos(radians(Location.latitude)) * cos(radians(Location.longitude) - radians('-74.0265')) + sin(radians('40.181')) * sin(radians(Location.latitude)))) AS distance
 , Item.idItem
 , Item.dateAdded
 , Item.fidLocation
 , Item.itemName
 , Item.description
 , Item.fullImageName
 , Item.thumbnailImageName
 , @level := IF(@group = idLocation, @level+1, 1) AS level
 , @group := idLocation as tempGroup 
FROM
  Location
INNER JOIN Item
ON Location.idLocation = Item.fidLocation
order by idLocation, RAND(),
HAVING distance < '1000' AND level <= 5
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, that is kind of working.  What are the @ operators called so I can look that up and learn about it

Comment: `@` is not an operator, it's the prefix required on user-defined variables. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/user-variables.html